# ASP.NET MVC 4 - WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection called multiple times error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, simplemembership

I have a Seed method in my Migrations/Configuration.cs:

```
  protected override void Seed(MVC4App.Models.MVC4Entities context)
  {
     try
     {
        // Initialize database for Account
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
           "MVC4Entities", "Users", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
```

If I try and run 'update-database -verbose' on my dev machine I get this error:

```
The "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method can be called only once.
```

That is the only place in my code that it is called. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a check for initialization :

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
{
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
           "MVC4Entities", "Users", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
}
```

Comment: for your application I couldn't tell you im afraid without looking at it.  for myself it was something to do with the DI framework (in this case autofac) so maybe a place to look if you are using one.